# What is the right formula for weight update rule in Logistic Regression using stochastic gradient descent

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, logistic-regression

Apologies for the lengthy title.
My question is about the weight update rule for logistic regression using stochastic gradient descent.

I have just started experimenting on Logistic Regression. I came across two weight update expressions and did not know which one is more accurate and why they are different.

**The first Method:**

Source: (Book) Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach by Norvig, Russell
 on page 726-727:
using the L2 loss function:

[image]

[image]

where
g stands for the logistic function
g' stands for g's derivative
w stands for weight
hw(x) represents the logistic regression hypothesis

**The other method:**

Source (Paper authored by Charles Elkan): Logistic Regression and Stochastic Gradient Training.

can be found [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.169.3611&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

[image]

Comment: How do you like that AI book? It’s on my reading list but I’ve done a fair amount of machine learning, deep learning, and now some RL, so I didn’t know how much would be new info. Would be interested in your take on it.

Comment: @Hanzy Hi, well to be honest, my strategy is to search the subject at hand over several books. Thus, I don’t go through a whole book. However, what I likes about it is the clarity and it was used by an AI veteran of https://machinelearningmastery.com.